# Copy directory content separated by modified dates and customerName

Tags: powershell, directory

I have a letter backup folder that has this structure:

```
F:\Shares\Ltrstore\Backup\20160626-modifieddate\pathto\x$\Production\Letters\customer1\contentIwant1
F:\Shares\Ltrstore\Backup\20160626-modifieddate\pathto\x$\Production\Letters\customer2\contentIwant1
F:\Shares\Ltrstore\Backup\20160625-modifieddate\pathto\x$\Production\Letters\customer1\contentIwant2
F:\Shares\Ltrstore\Backup\20160625-modifieddate\pathto\x$\Production\Letters\customer2\contentIwant2
```

How can I use `copy-item`, and `get-chilitem` in Powershell to copy the content I want from these different folders?

Each day these letter content is backed up in that location for different customers. However, in this case I want the letters for cust1 and cust2 for all the dates.

Comment: I don't understand which directories you want.  You want essentially this `F:\Shares\Ltrstore\Backup\*\pathto\x$\Production\Letters\customer2\contentIwant1`
?

Comment: There are multiple directories like this that are separated by the dates; the letters in the directory are different for each day for the customer(cust1 and 2).

Comment: so there is: directory 1 for today, directory 2 for yesterday, directory 3 for the day before etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to grab all of the files for customer 1 and customer 2 in that path, here's how you do it.

```
$files = Dir F:\Shares\Ltrstore\Backup -recurse
$cust1 = $files | Where FullName -like "*\customer1\*"
$cust2 = $files | Where FullName -like "*\customer2\*"

#Do something with the files
$cust1 | copy-item -destination C:\NewPath -WhatIf
```

Here's how this works.  We start by setting `$files` to contain every file in that backup path.  Then, we set `$cust1` equal to `$files`, and use the `Where-Object` cmdlet (Which is one of PowerShell's many tricks to search and find matches) and look at the FullName property of each file.

The FullName will hold the files complete path, so we can use that to wildcard search for the customer name we want.

Finally at the end, there's an example of how to copy those files to a new folder for review.

Comment: That idea sounds like it will work testing it out now...Thanks @foxDeploy

Comment: If this helped you, be sure to upvote and mark as answer!  And welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: The previous script took a really long time and never did complete and resulted in the shutdown of the server as it was consuming too much resources. I made some tweaks, I will wait for off peak period today before I run it. Here are the changes I made:

Comment: $backuplist = Get-ChildItem "E:\Shares\Ltrstore\Backup"
    ForEach ($dir in $backuplist) {
    $letters= dir $dir.FullName -Recurse
    $cust1 = $letters | Where FullName -like "*cust1*"
    $cust2 = $letters | Where FullName -like "*cust2*"
    $cust1 | Copy-Item -Destination E:\TempLetters\cust1
    $cust2 | Copy-Item -Destination E:\TempLetters\cust2
    }

Comment: The logic now runs in a ForEach loop.
Previously, the entire resursive directory structure and all of its metadata was being held in $letters.  This undoubtedly took not only a massive amount of RAM but also delayed the program from doing anything while it recursed through that directory. Now, it just gets all the directory names within the path held in $backuplist, non-recursively.  The ForEach then operates out of each of the individual child objects

Comment: This drastically reduces the RAM needed, as the previous directory’s metadata is thrown out as it moves on to the next.  I ran a WhatIf for the copies (which does everything but the I/O) and the script only hovered around 120 MB.  This might go up slightly, but I can’t imagine by much.
This also means the script almost immediately begins to copy files.